# Starting out with Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just started out with Java and I am playing around with codes I copied online. I copied this code online and tried to run it on eclipse

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/12types/SpringSeason.java.html

```
public class SpringSeason { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int month = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int day   = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        boolean isSpring =  (month == 3 && day >= 20 && day <= 31)
                         || (month == 4 && day >=  1 && day <= 30)
                         || (month == 5 && day >=  1 && day <= 31)
                         || (month == 6 && day >=  1 && day <= 20);

        System.out.println(isSpring);
    }
}
```

and I keep getting this error on eclipse

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at trollstartwo.main(trollstartwo.java:4)

Comment: You need to pass it 2 parameters when you run it, e.g. `java SpringSeason 3 16`

Comment: How are you calling your program? It expects to be passed two parameters on the command line: `java SpringSeason 3 20`.

Comment: Note this is described at the top of the file linked.

Comment: The following could be helpful: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html

Comment: Your title gives me chills...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to execute a java program with arguments in console and eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914019/not-able-to-execute-a-java-program-with-arguments-in-console-and-eclipse)

Comment: search for answers before posting question.

Answer (score 1):

The **args[0]** refers to the String array **args[]** which is a parameter of the main method.

```
.... void main(String[] args) //this args array here
```

The values of the **args[]** array are provided by the user while running the program. While running the program, you might see an option in Eclipse for ***main method arguments***. You have to provide the values for **args[0]** and **args[1]** there. If you don't do that, the array **args[]** is not even initialised, i.e., it remains an array of 0 spaces. So when the program tries to access the values at 0 and 1 position of args[], it doesn't even find those positions and thus the **ArrayIndexOutOfBounds** exception is thrown during runtime.

To avoid this, provide values in the main method arguments box. Suppose if you wanna provide '4' for month and '5' for day, type **{"4", "5"}** in the box.